# initializing a UIBarButtonItem with a UIImage and resizing the image in iOS

Tags: ios, resize, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem, image-resizing

I am trying to initialize a UIBarButtonItem with an Image. The available method is initWithImage. When I do this, the image is just a block of color. I want to be able to resize this image. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Internal UIBarButtonItem images need to be one solid color (system turns it into white if you don't) with an alpha channel for transparency.

Comment: the image that I want to use is completely white. I tried using drawInRect on UIImage but that still gives me a block of white color. The drawInRect is supposed to draw the image within the rectangle specified but that's not happening.

Comment: Does it have an alpha channel? What's the file type? Can you post the image and the code you're using to insert it?